# How to label the origin as (0, 0) instead of (0.0, 0.0)

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

I am plotting a function by the following code:

```
Plot[x^2/5 + 1, {x, 0, 3}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
     PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

In the output, the `AxesOrigin` point is shown as `(0.0, 0.0)`. How to make *Mathematica* label the origin as `(0, 0)` instead of `(0.0, 0.0)`?

[image]

Comment: Is it [code or codes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/258852/a-single-line-of-code-or-codes)?

Comment: @Syed Does this really matter?

Comment: @Syed I'd say you don't need to ask. Just edit the post if you find something can be improved, this is how this site is designed. You can add that link in comment if you feel it better to explain, of course.

Comment: @xzczd I edited the OP's previous question.

Comment: @Syed Then I'd still say you don't need to ask :) . Just leave that link as a explanation (if you've edited again) or a suggestion (if you're not in the mood to edit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I won't be surprised if this is a duplicate, but it's easier for me to write an answer:

```
p = Plot[x^2/5 + 1, {x, 0, 3}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> False];

Show[p, AbsoluteOptions[p, Ticks] /. "0.0" -> "0"]
```

Comment: @YaHe Notice it's actually not `'` but `\``. In comment you can add a \ before ` to make it display correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find any posts relevant to this quesition. I find another solution to this problem. Use `Ticks` to specify the tick labels explicitly: `Ticks -> {{0, 0.5, 1.0\`\`2, 1.5, 2.0\`\`2, 2.5, 3.0\`\`2}, {0, 0.5, 1.0\`\`2, 1.5, 2.0\`\`2, 2.5}}`

Comment: Thanks for your information. I have corrected the code.

Answer (score 2):

One can use `FrameTicks` to label the numbers along the axes.

```
 Plot[x^2/5 + 1, {x, 0, 3}, 
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},   
      PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
      PlotRangeClipping -> False, Frame -> True,   
      FrameTicks -> {{{{2.5, "2.5", {0.012, 0}}, {2, "2", {0.012, 0}}, 
                       {1.5, "1.5", {0.012, 0}}, {1, "1", {0.012, 0}}, 
                       {0.5, "0.5", {0.012, 0}}, {0, "0", {0.012, 0}}}, {}}, 
                     {{{0, "0", {0.012, 0}}, {0.5, "0.5", {0.012, 0}}, 
                       {1, "1", {0.012, 0}}, {1.5, "1.5", {0.012, 0}}, 
                       {2, "2", {0.024, 0}}, {2.5, "2.5", {0.012, 0}}, 
                       {3, "3", {0.012, 0}}}, {}}},   
      FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 15]]
```